Measure execution time, but also in case of exceptions
I am writing some code that I would like to add prometheus metrics. In the metrics we want to measure the time it took, but also in case a exception was raised.
I ended up with this code, but it feels as if it can be written a bit better, but i dont know how to achieve it:
def async_load_one(self, result, **fields):
    start = time()
    end = 0
    status = ""
    try:
        result.set(self.table.query(**fields))
        end = time()
        status = "ok"
    except Exception as e:
        result.set_exception(e)
        end = time()
        status = "error"
    finally:
        elapsed = end - start
        DYNAMO_ACCESS_DURATION.labels(
            operation="load_one",
            status=status
            ).observe(elapsed)



The finally clause runs whether or not the try statement produces an exception. Meaning it will execute in any event.
So you can do:
def func():
    start = time()
    try:
        print("do something")
        status = "ok"
    except Exception as e:
        print("an error has occurred", e)
        status = "error"
    finally:
        end = time()
        elapsed = end - start
        print(f"{elapsed=}")
        print(f"{status=}")

Which prints something like this when no errors are raised:
do something
elapsed=1.3828277587890625e-05
status='ok'

Or this if an error were to be raised in the try block:
do something
an error has occurred 
elapsed=2.09808349609375e-05
status='error'


If you need to do this in more than one method/function, you can consider using a decorator:
def timing_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            status = "ok"
        except Exception as e:
            print("an error has occurred", e)
            status = "error"
            result = None
        finally:
            end = time.time()
            elapsed = end - start
            print(f"{elapsed=}")
            print(f"{status=}")
        return result

    return wrapper


@timing_decorator
def func():
    print("do something")


Not sure about the prometheus details but would this work if you put what you have in finally in a function and call it in both there and error handling?
def report_time(method_name, elapsed, status):
   DYNAMO_ACCESS_DURATION.labels(
                operation=method_name,
                status=status
                ).observe(elapsed)

# and
...
        except Exception as e:
            result.set_exception(e)
            end = time()
            status = "error"
            report_time("load_one", end - start, status)
        finally:
            elapsed = end - start
            report_time("load_one", end - start, status)

It can be beautified but that's the idea.
